# Jquery validation - removes error class in the other field

Tags: jquery

I am using 3 fields. Value of field 3 should have a 500 difference with summation of field 1 and field 2 values. Else these 3 fields should highlight with error. Else error class will be removing from these 3 fields.(This validation is used in these 3 field). But the same time, field 2 only allows a value range of 1000 to 2000. If field 2 contains value 3000, and it is highlighting, and when we click any other field ( which has the other validation), the error class is getting removed. How to solve this ?

```
$.validator.addMethod("compareWeights", function(value, element) {
    var total = 0;
    var difference = 0;
    var valuef3 = $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field3').val();
    var tareWeight = $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field2').val();
    if ($(element).val() === '' || valuef3 === '') {
        return true;
    }
        total = parseInt(tareWeight)+parseInt($(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field1').val());

    difference = Math.abs(total - valuef3);
    if (difference >  500){
        $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field1').addClass('error');
        if (!$(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field2').prop('disabled')){
            $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field2').addClass('error');
        }
        if (!$(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field3').prop('disabled')){
                $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field3').addClass('error');        
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field1').removeClass('error');
        $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field2').removeClass('error');
        $(element).closest('.row .field').find('.field3').removeClass('error');
        return true;
    }
});
```

After this validation, the error highlighted(if the value not in a range 1000-2000) in field2 is getting removed. If I click the field again, it shows error.

HTML Code :

```
<div class="${selectedSpan4} piece-count-span2">
                                <span class="muted cargo-weight-text-inline">&{'weight.label'}</span><br>
                                <input type="text" class="field1 compareWeights"  value="${weight}" title="&{'cargo.weight'}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="${selectedSpan4} piece-count-span2">
                               <span class="muted">&{'tare.label'} </span><br>
                               <input type="text" 
                                             class="field2 compareWeights vgm-range-check fullWidth" value="${tare} title="&{'tare.title'}" />
                            </div>

                              <div class="${selectedSpan4} ${marginLeft0} piece-count-span1">
                                    <span class="muted">&{'cargo.label'} )</span><br>
                                    <input type="text" value="${vgm}"  
                                            class="field3 compareWeights fullWidth" title="&{'containers.vgm'}" />
                              </div>

                    </div>
```

vgm-range-check : is the validation for field2 to check the 1000 to 2000 range

Comment: share your html code also

Comment: @Udara Kasun : Html code added above

Comment: @UdaraKasun : Any updates?

Comment: Where validation initialization part?